# ImageView in Xamarin.iOS LaunchScreens: Set image

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, storyboard

I want to change/set the image in my launch screen for my Xamarin.iOS App.
Opening LaunchScreen.storyboard in my Visual Studio 2017 (Win10), I get the storyboard editor as expected.
But if I want to change (or even set) the Image-Property of the default  ImageView (or a newly added one), the default file open dialogs comes up - and no matter what image file I select, nothing changes.

Do the images for the launch screen storyboard comply some criteria? e.g. filetype? location?

**Update:**
This is the property I try to set with an image:
[image]

As files I tried several PNG images - all working well as images in my normal Xamarin Views or as Icons.

Comment: Which property did you change? What kind of image type did you select?

Comment: I update my post with this information :-)

Comment: Do you have the image in the folder? If yes then you have to provide the path "folder name/image name".

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is that you can try this way,rebuild your project when you create a new `xarmain.ios` project.
 [Try the following steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OI2tu.png)